# C# interface calling Python

Tags: c#, python, .net

If I have an UI written using C#, and I'd like to press a button and call a python script (which depends on a number of external python library, such as matplotlib). My final application have to be deployed in Windows platform. Which should be the approach to do?

1. IronPython: It does not support Python3 yet, and I cannot use it.
2. Python For .NET: I still get confused on the use of Python for .NET, can this serve my purpose? Any recommended tutorial?
3. Calling Python script with StartProcessInfo class of C#. I can do it, but I feel that it is not the most elegant way to do so.
4. Python rest API. However, there will be overhead on setting up server etc.

Which should be the way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

"Calling Python script with StartProcessInfo"  is clean and hassle-free.